# Rails: how to remember a user persistently if he logs in from multiple browsers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, remember-me

My implementation for remembering a user persistently is as follows (I am not using any gem for authentication):

1. User logs in from Firefox, provides credentials and selects Remember_me option.
2. User is authenticated and a remember_token is created and placed in the cookies hash. A remember_digest corresponding to the remember_token is saved in the user table. User quits Firefox.
3. User does step1 except that he does it from Chrome.
4. Step2 is performed. **Unfortunately, the existing remember_digest in the db is now overwritten with a new value.**
5. User launches Firefox again. **But Rails cannot match the remember_token sent by Firefox with the remember_digest.**

   What can I do to get around this? Do I need to maintain multiple digest columns? If so, how many? Or, is it even worth doing it?

Comment: save the remember token in form of array in db. I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: I would also suggest to implement a relationship in your model that a user `has_many :remember_digests`. You could also store the browser to that model, so that the user has an overview, from which browsers he logs in

Comment: Do you have a sessions controller in your app?

Comment: @Valerie Yes, I have a Sessions controller which is responsible for creating a new sessions.

Comment: @23tux Are you suggesting that :remember_digest should be stored in a separate table rather than in the User table?

Comment: Do you handle user credentialing in session controller? The user should have only one remember_digest, but it has to accessed at the session level. It's hard for me to guess what's going on here without more controller and model code.

Comment: I would recommend reviewing this tutorial with structure and code for a complete user authentication system from the Michael Hartl tutorial. It's long, and detailed, but if you follow it, you will have working user authenication: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users

Comment: @ValAsensio There is only one remember_digest per user. This remember_digest is created when the user logs in from a browser. If he logs in from another browser, the remember_digest is overwritten with the value from the new browser. I have read the tutorial by Michael Hartl. It does not cover the scenario I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Ahoy gem](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy_email) for your purpose